# PocketSphinx - getHypstr() returns empty for KeyphraseSearch after processRaw

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

Trying **edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx** with processRaw to detect a keyword.

I have setup the SpeechRecognizer's decoder directly with getDecoder().**setKeyphrase**(KWS_SEARCH,KEYPHRASE);
First calling decoder.**startUtt**(); then few calls to **processRaw** with slices of a PCM buffer then calling decoder.**endUtt**(). I get an empty hypothesis for decoder.**hyp**();

Have tried few different values for **setKeywordThreshold**. No luck.

1. What's missing?
2. To my understanding When calling **processRaw** the last parameter **full_utt** should be False until calling **endUtt**, is that correct?
3. When should **full_utt** be set to True? and how does it affect the recognition?

Edited:
Need to mention that at first I am trying to detect "oh mighty computer" phrase which is exactly the demo phrase which is already recognized correctly using the SpeechRecognizer's own **RecognizerThread**
yet when using **processRaw** got no detection. The audio conditions are the same for both attempts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> What's missing?

You missed the [tutorial recommendation](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutoriallm/#keyword-lists):

> The threshold must be tuned to balance between false alarms and missed
>   detections. **The best way to do this is to use a prerecorded audio
>   file.** The common tuning process is the following:
>
> Take a long recording with few occurrences of your keywords and some
>   other sounds. You can take a movie sound or something else. The length
>   of the audio should be approximately 1 hour. Run a keyword spotting on
>   that file with different thresholds for every keyword, use the
>   following command:  pocketsphinx_continuous -infile 
>   -keyphrase  \   -kws_threshold  -time yes The command will print many lines, some of them are keywords with
>   detection times and confidences. You can also disable extra logs with
>   the -logfn your_file.log option to avoid clutter.
>
> From your keyword spotting results count how many false alarms and
>   missed detections you’ve encountered. Select the threshold with the
>   smallest amount of false alarms and missed detections. For the best
>   accuracy it is better to have a keyphrase with 3-4 syllables. Too
>   short phrases are easily confused.